# How to add a system call to the Linux Kernel?

Tags: kernel, programming

I'm currently reading *Operating System Concepts* 7th edition by Silberschartz, Galvin and Gagne. At the end of chapter 2, there is an exercise "Add a system call to the Linux Kernel". Unfortunately, I realized the directory structure that the authors used is completely different with Ubuntu's one. For example, the authors referred to "/usr/src/linux-2.x/include/asm-i386/unistd.h", but on my machine, they are:

- /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-10
- /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic

And inside this folder, I couldn't find anything called "asm-i386" :(. I wonder is there a documentation specified for Ubuntu? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't do anything special. Your first difficulty is that you don't have the kernel source installed, only kernel headers. The authors are describing a system with a copy of the kernel source in `/usr/src/linux-2.x`. If you're only compiling external modules, the headers, which are what you see on your system, are enough. Ubuntu ships kernel headers for that purpose in the `linux-headers-*` packages (which you would normally install via the dependency from the [linux-headers-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-headers-generic) [image: Install linux-headers-generic] metapackage). If you need the whole source, get a compressed archive from the [linux-source-2.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-source-2.6) [image: Install linux-source-2.6] binary package.

Another thing is that the directory structure has changed a little over time; architecture-dependent headers moved from `include/asm-$ARCH` to `arch/$ARCH/include/asm`. Furthermore the `i386` and `x86_64` architectures were merged into a unified `x86` in 2.6.24. ([More details here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/where-did-trampoline-s-go/12564#12564)) So you now need to look in `arch/x86/include` rather than `include/asm-i386`.

Here are a few useful resources for Linux kernel hackers:

- [*Linux Device Drivers* (LDD3)](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)
- [LWN](http://lwn.net/) (news about Linux, including many technical articles about the kernel by one of the authors of LDD)
- [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux) to browse and search the kernel source
- [LKML](https://lkml.org/) (the Linux kernel mailing list), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) to ask questions about the kernel and kernel development

And also read [this thread on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/797/understanding-the-linux-kernel-source), which explains how to locate the implementation of an existing syscall.

Comment: Nice answer! I just ran `find /usr/src -type f -name unistd.h` for my answer :)

Comment: @Gilles: I was a bit confused with the author's instruction. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic/include/linux/unistd.h`

or in future kernels:

`/usr/src/linux-headers-KERNEL_VERSION/include/asm-generic/unistd.h`

:)